# Using host filesystem as a read-only base in docker

Tags: docker, volumes

In docker, is it possible to use part of the host's filesystem to be mounted as read-only in the docker image but any write on it will be on the COW/UFS layer? Below is the usecase I am looking at.

1) We have a proprietary product that takes forever to install with lots of manual intervention. However once the install base is completed the core files are almost not changed as it allows a node-level configuration to be placed in a separate directory that just references the install base. Of course if we need to update the core files then it will be on the host. The core installation will take up about 8GB file space on the host machine.

The host core installation may be virtualized (VMWare or VirtualBox).

2) The core installation would also write its metadata on a database, and each created node will write additional metadata stuff on it. If the DB installation is on the host, can docker run the DB process on a docker image and just reference the DB binaries and data partition as read-only, but write its changes on the data partition on the layer?

If it helps here is a sample relationship I am looking at:
  -> Host is a VirtualBox running CentOS, and has the installation of proprietary product and its database.
  -> Container A1 will spawn a database process based on the existing database state (empty except for the metadata made during installation).
  -> Container A2 will spawn a product process, create the product node using the database offered by A1, and run the build,test,deploy routines.

I need to spawn multiple pairs of the node+database on demand for continuous integration. The setup above should allow me to bring up Container pairs for each isolated node that is needed by our development team. Theoretically I can mount the product base directory as read/write but I think there will be some operations that write data on it (e.g. logs) that I would like to be done on the product process layer instead.

Thanks.

Comment: Your requirements describe how Docker images and containers work. Mounted directories don't work in the same manner. Is there any reason you aren't creating an image from the install base and initial metadata?

Comment: Size of image that will be created is my primary consideration. We will be using a non-public repository that caps the size of images to 2GB. I might be able to get away with layering the installation to produce images under 2GB but not knowing everything about the product might entail maintenance headaches on upgrades if I split them to layers.

Comment: I have already created the proof of concept VirtualBox image which when exported to a vagrant box results only to around 3GB compressed. Pulling that once over the local network via rsync might also be more economical than having 40 developers pull a set of  2GB docker images from an external repository. At this point these are already internal policy restrictions that we have to work with.

Comment: Could the binaries be mounted RO from the host to all containers and just the database copied into each container before creation? Another option could be to create your own OverlayFS/aufs file system of your application for each container and mount that.

Comment: vagrant sounds like a good choice with those restrictions.

Comment: Thanks Matt. Ill take a look at the read-only mounting option. I think some logs may be created for each node but I may be able to workaround that using some symlinks. We are already using vagrant for VBox images.